# DateTimeFormatter zero out empty

Tags: java

is there a way to have a DateTimeFormatter like that

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
```

and it should convert to a LocalDateTime and just zero out whats missing?

Actually on Joda there was DateTimeFormat which gave back a DateTime and not a exception. Is there any equivalent to that?

```
val formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern)
formatter.parseDateTime(data).toDate
```

will always yield a real date no matter what the pattern is while on java8 it says its missing LocalDate.

Actually the pattern should be variable so that people could either insert HH:mm and dd.MM.yyyy and always get a LocalDateTime, that should be initalized / defaulted to 1970-01-01T00:00.

So doing:

```
// with pattern HH:mm
formatter.parse("00:00") should yield LocalDateTime.of(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0)

// with pattern YYYY-mm
formatter.parse("2016-11") should yield LocalDateTime.of(2016, 11, 01, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for.  Are you looking *exclusively* for hours and seconds, or are you interested in a day permanently set to midnight?

Comment: can you post more codes?

Comment: Not much of a fan of the multiple pattern piece; there are smarter ways to handle this sort of thing as opposed to this.  You can use a `LocalTime` to handle the time, and a `LocalDate` to handle the date aspect.  Naturally, the date pattern has to have a day attached to it (unless you always want to assume the first of the month).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in defaults. *You* have to provide the missing values.

```
// Parse HH:mm
LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalTime.parse("12:34")
                              .atDate(LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1));
System.out.println(ldt1); // Prints 1970-01-01T12:34

// Parse YYYY-mm
LocalDateTime ldt2 = YearMonth.parse("2016-11")
                              .atDay(1)
                              .atStartOfDay();
System.out.println(ldt2); // Prints 2016-11-01T00:00
```

Notice that you didn't even need a `DateTimeFormatter` for any of them.

---

**UPDATE**

If you must use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), then you can create one using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), where you can supply missing values using the [`parseDefaulting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) method.

```
// Parse HH:mm
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("HH:mm") // other time fields default to 0, see "Resolving"
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY, 0) // short for 1970-01-01
        .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("12:34", formatter1);
System.out.println(ldt1); // Prints 1970-01-01T12:34

// Parse YYYY-mm
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuu-MM")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1) // see resolveDate()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0) // short for 00:00:00.000000000
        .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-11", formatter2);
System.out.println(ldt2); // Prints 2016-11-01T00:00
```

As for which fields are required for successful parsing, see:

- [DateTimeFormatter - Resolving](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#resolving)
- [IsoChronology.resolveDate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html#resolveDate-java.util.Map-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-)

Comment: actually what I really wanted is to make use of variable patterns.. So even if your answer is correct it doesn't really suite my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this solution works for me but I doubt it's not a "generic" answer since I only needed LocalDateTime and its also scala:

```
object MyDate {
  def parse(text: CharSequence, formatter: DateTimeFormatter): MyDate = new MyDate(formatter.parse(text))
}

class MyDate(accessor: TemporalAccessor) {

  private[this] def getOrDefault(field: TemporalField, default: Int): Int = {
    if (accessor.isSupported(field)) accessor.get(field) else default
  }

  def toLocalDateTime: LocalDateTime = {
    val year: Int = getOrDefault(ChronoField.YEAR, 1970)
    val month: Int = getOrDefault(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
    val day: Int = getOrDefault(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    val hour: Int = getOrDefault(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    val minute: Int = getOrDefault(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)

    LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute)
  }

}
```